# How is SVG images reaction on "onclick" method - at an example

Tags: javascript, svg

I've attached "onclick" to my SVG image and expected after user click on that picture It will change it's colour ("fill" property) to pink, but it doesn't happen, why ?
I did the same for button ("Color me red") to change stroke for red and it works fine. As I know SVG images are sensitive for "onclick" method (I've read about that and ... tried - my own created SVG rectangular changes colour and it works like a charm. I'll be grateful for any help as I'm little confused about that.

```
var beet=document.getElementsByTagName("path");

beet.addEventlistener("click", function(){  
 beet.style.fill="purple";
});
```

https://codepen.io/zeeebra/pen/awqPoG

Comment: beet is not a path, it's a collection of path elements. Iterate over them to add event listeners to them all.

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson it now gives me an error "unexpected identifier" despite I'm rather sure that I've created niece loop, any suggestions ? var beet=document.getElementsByTagName('path');

for(int i=0; i<beet.length; i++){
  
 beet[i].addEventListener("click", colorPurple) 
}

function colorPurple(){
  beet.style.fill="purple"; 
}

Comment: It should be `for(var i=0;...etc...`. Ie. `var`, not `int`.